# Convert jquery code to angular to add classes dynamically on function call from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, element

I;m having Jquery code that adds class dynamically on function call and I'm passing argumaents based on different conditions.

```
function setClasses(index, steps) {
    $(".step-wizard ul li:lt(" + index + ")").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    });
    $(".step-wizard  ul li:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active")
    var p = index * (100 / steps);
    $("#prog").width(p + '%');
}
setClasses(3, 4);
```

Since I'm using typescript and angular(1.5.6)I wanted to convert the above code to function using angular's built in DOM manipulation functions.

Below is the one that I tried :

```
function setClasses(index,steps) {
    let myEl1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('.step-wizard ul li:lt'));               
    var myEl2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('.step-wizard  ul li:eq'));
    myEl1.addClass('done');
    myEl2.addClass('visited');
    let p = index * (100 / steps);
    myEl2.setWidth(p + '%'); //setWidth is not a angular.element property
}
setClasses(3, 4);
```

I'm not sure how can I add the below part and also to set the width:

```
$(".step-wizard ul li:lt(" + index + ")").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

Please suggest some good conversion techniques for DOM manipulation using angular built in functions [Reference(angular.element)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: what is the `index` value? you are just passing a single value but repeating as `each`

Comment: yes index is a single value.Here is the original code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgaBGN

Comment: I am able to see only `Loading...........`

Comment: Please find the plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/2bH02xQipuvlavGpdLn2?p=preview

Comment: What happens if I pass `3` as `index` value? Can you explain the last code of your question? Is that adding class `done` to first three `li` elements?

Comment: Okay I understood

Comment: Yes ,it'll add class `done` to first three `li` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the working plunker with angular code https://plnkr.co/edit/URWgTCRP2TeT9tNvuwzY?p=preview

Yeah, done. remove below lines

```
$(".step-wizard ul li:lt(" + index + ")").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

Add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

below the jquery source file in index.html.

Replce the removed lines with beolw code.

```
var elems = [];
for(i=0;i<index;i++){
  elems.push(angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("li"))[i])
}
angular.forEach(elems, function(value, key){
   var a = angular.element(value);
   a.addClass('done');
});
```

I am unable to save the plunker as it is private

Comment: Thanks,Please check the plunker link.Its the same as that in the question

Comment: No, I changed the the above code in `script.js`. Please see that

Comment: And how about  $("#prog").width(p + '%'); ?

Comment: I just do that only. You can do by taking it as a reference